# How to access child controller method of directive when isolated scope is not created

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am trying to create one directive which has its own controller which contains some methods. I am setting `scope:false` to ensure that the directive will not create an isolated scope.

Directive Definition is :

```
angular.controller("myController", function($scope){
      var parentCtrl = this;
      parentCtrl.otherMethod = function(){
       //Method body
    }
})
angular.directive('customDirective',function(){
   return {
         scope : false,
         controller: function(){
               var ctrl = this;
               this.someMethod = function($scope){
                   console.log("Hello World");
               }
         }
  }
});
```

usage:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
   <custom-directive>
      <button ng-click="someMethod()">click me</button>
   </custom-directive>
</div>
```

I am unable to access the method `someMethod()`.
I am not even getting it inside any scope when I am trying to find it through batarang.
Can someone help?

Comment: Provide your code within a jsfiddle or other alternative

Comment: Below is a link for Plnkr simulating the issue.http://plnkr.co/edit/fVJwbf?p=preview